# Prevent Filter chain from execution based on condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

In my spring boot application I have the following filter registry:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistry filterRegistry(Service1 service1, Service2 service2,
            EvictionService evictionService) throws GeneralSecurityException {
      FilterRegistry r = FilterRegistry.instance();

      r.put("filter1", new MetadataFilter(Service2,evictionService));
      r.put("filter2", new RoutesFilter(service1,evictionService, publicKey));

      return r;
}
```

In the first filter I need to check on a condition, if this condition is true I want to skip all filters in my filter registry. What I am having now is that I do the check in the beginning of each filter like this:

```
public class Filter1 extends ZuulFilter {
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
            if(condition){
            return false;
            }
            return true
    }

}

public class Filter2 extends ZuulFilter {
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
            if(condition){
            return false;
            }
            return true
    }

}
```

but What I really want is to create a new filter that holds the condition, run the condition filter at the beginning and if condition is true then do not continue in the filter registry execution.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved logically by adding a request attribute in your decision filter.

The Decision Making Filter should look like following.

```
public class DecisionFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    // .... Other methods and codes

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        if(shouldExecuteFilter1()) {
            request.setAttribute("executeFilter1", true);
        } 

        if (shouldExecuteFilter2()) {
            request.setAttribute("executeFilter2", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the Operational Filters will just fetch the corresponding attribute from request and execute the operation if true.

```
public class FilterOne extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();

        if (servletRequest.getAttribute("executeFilter1") != null || ((Boolean) servletRequest.getAttribute("executeFilter1"))) {
            // Perform your task
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly you can implement any number of filters with one decision making filter which runs first.

Comment: this will work definitely, thanks for the answer. However I was looking for an answer that  actually doesn't add any conditions to the existing filters

Comment: Implementing such conditional execution of filters without changing code in filters itself is not possible because it requires to check data at runtime and you cannot update filter registry at runtime.